# Помогите написать sql запрос

Tags: sql

Добрый день. Помогите написать запрос.

Есть вот такая таблица:
[image: таблица]

В конечно итоге необходимо получить сумму значений за определенный год по столбцу `ticket`.
 Т.е запрос: высчитываем все значения по данным столбцам, потом выбираем нужную дату и подбиваем итог по кол-ву записей за эту дату.

Причем учесть то, чтобы повторы не попадали в итог, только уникальные значения за эту дату.

Comment: что вы уже пытались сделать сами ? прочитали вы что такое group by и функции count()/sum()

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно вначале вытащить уникальные значения, а потом проссумировать с группировкой по полю `data`

```sql
SELECT
  data,
  SUM(ticket)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT data, ticket FROM mytable
)
GROUP BY
  data
```

Comment: Вы прямо экстрасенс. я по тексту в вопросе "_подбивает итог по кол-ву записей за эту дату_" решил бы, что это count(), а не sum(). Тем более, что ведущие нули в ticket говорят о том, что это char и делать его sum бессмысленно. А вообще мы стараемся не отвечать на плохо сформулированные вопросы, в которых автор не указал на свои попытки решения. это же явное домашнее задание ...

Comment: @Mike ведущие нули, скорее всего, последствия флага `ZEROFILL`. Ну и сумма по строкам отлично считается. Сервер сам переводит строки в числа

Comment: Ой, тогда вы точно экстрасенс, как вы догадались, что речь идет о MySQL

Comment: Сам ничего не пробовал еще.

Comment: А как указать например, чтобы он каждый день вычитывал все с 00-00 и до 23-59. Новый день с чистого листа. И на счет столбца тикет , это зарегистрированные клиенты. Образно так написал.  А в принципе там могут быть значения и с цифрами и с буквами.

Comment: @АлексейНовиков Ну так попробуйте, SQL базового уровня изучается за день, на каком нибудь sql-ex.ru. И постарайтесь точнее формулировать задачу, лично я не понял сумма значений тикетов вам нужна или количество уникальных, на определенную дату или в разрезе дат. И какая конкретно БД имеется в виду. MS SQL например на приведенном в этом ответе запросе даст ошибку, если ticcket символьное, а не числовое поле

Comment: @АлексейНовиков В приведенном вами примере данных я не вижу ни дат ни времени. Обязательно указывайте какая у вас СУБД и какие типы данных у столбцов (лучше прямо в виде create table, что бы проще было тестовую таблицу для проверки ответа создать).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(buf.ticket)
FROM (SELECT ticket
    FROM eshko_2016_04.test
    WHERE date = 2015
    GROUP BY ticket) AS buf;
```